# How to bold portion of text in a checkbox option in contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, contact-form, wordpress-shortcode

I am trying to make bold specific text that is part of the checkbox options for a contact form 7 form.

the current checkbox shortcode is:

```
[checkbox* Location use_label_element exclusive "Michigan City Library 100 E 4th St, Michigan City, IN 46360" "La Porte Library 904 Indiana Ave, La Porte, IN 46350"]
```

I am wanting to bold only the text that says "Michigan City Library" and the text that says "La Porte Library"

Is there a way to do this? I have tried using `<b>` as well as using css to select the options but havent found how to target the specific text while leaving the rest of the text normal.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you add the raw HTML? Notice how I wrapped `<span class='bold-text'>` around Michigan City Library... maybe that'll work.

```
[checkbox* Location use_label_element exclusive "<span class='bold-text'>Michigan City Library</span> 100 E 4th St, Michigan City, IN 46360" "<span class='bold-text'>La Porte Library</span> 904 Indiana Ave, La Porte, IN 46350"]
```

Remember to add CSS too:

```
.bold-text {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```